# Count occurrences of string from every column (Postgres)

Tags: sql, postgresql, performance

So I have a database with a simple structure like this

```
  CAT   | DOG   | FISH   
+-------+-------+--------+
| red   | blue  | orange |
+-------+-------+--------+
| green | black | white  |
+-------+-------+--------+
| red   | black | orange |
+-------+-------+--------+
```

I want to be able to get a table or object or something where it tells me the frequency of each string in each column. So when I run the query I want to see something like

```
{cat: {"red": 2, "green": 1}, dog: {"blue": 1, "black": 2} , fish: {"orange": 2, "white": 1}}
```

I just need the query to be fast. There will also be 10 columns rather than 3.

I've searched around but the only method I found was to get a count per one column, so it's like

```
SELECT cat, count(cat) FROM my_table GROUP BY cat
```

But what if I want the frequencies for **every** column by doing 1 query rather than 1 query for each column.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One method uses grouping sets:

```
select cat, dog, fish, count(*)
from t
group by grouping sets ( (cat), (dog), (fish) );
```

If your column types are compatible, you could also use a lateral join:

```
select v.colname, v.val, count(*)
from t cross join
     (values ('cat', cat), ('dog', dog), ('fish', fish)
     ) v(colname, val)
group by v.colname, val;
```

Comment: Thanks! Regarding speed, would one work better than the other? I don't know if I can do the lateral join way on the columns but the first way works fine. Just wondering if it'd work well if there were a lot of rows.

Comment: @WildWombat . . . I actually don't know.  You should try both.  My best guess is that `grouping sets` would be a bit faster on large data, because doing three separate aggregations on <n> rows should be faster than one aggregation on <3*n> rows.  But there might be other factors that affect performance as well.

Comment: Perfect, thanks! To be quite honest the first method makes more sense to me (I'm new to SQL) so I'll go with that for now! This is just a side question but is there a way to get the original number of rows as well using the first method? I'm charting this over some data and I can of course just add the count for all values in `dog` to get the total number, but is there a way to explicitly get it through sql

Comment: @WildWombat . . . Hummm . . . either `sum(count(*)) over ()` or `sum(count(*)) over () / 3`.  I don't use window functions much with `grouping sets`, but I'm guessing the first.

Answer (score 0):

You can unpivot with a lateral join, then aggregate:

```
select x.animal, x.color, count(*) cnt
from mytable t
cross join lateral (values('cat', cat), ('dog', dog), ('fish', fish)) x(animal, color)
group by x.animal, x.color
order by x.animal, x.color
```

**[Demo on DB Fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_12&fiddle=166519570b53f9c8aef7a5b29aea9966)**:

```
animal | color  | cnt
:----- | :----- | --:
cat    | green  |   1
cat    | red    |   2
dog    | black  |   2
dog    | blue   |   1
fish   | orange |   2
fish   | white  |   1
```